# Erro ao usar o cursor para ler tabela SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

porém ao meu ver o cursor foi inicializado corretamente na primeira posição como podem ver:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("meudb",MODE_PRIVATE,null);


db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pessoas(nome VARCHAR, IDADE INT(3))");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO PESSOAS(nome,idade) VALUES('davi', 25)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO PESSOAS(nome,idade) VALUES('marcos', 31)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO PESSOAS(nome,idade) VALUES('thiago', 50)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO PESSOAS(nome,idade) VALUES('bruna', 24)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO PESSOAS(nome,idade) VALUES('vanessa', 18)");




    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT nome,idade FROM pessoas",null);
    int colunaNome = cursor.getColumnIndex("nome");
    int colunaIdade = cursor.getColumnIndex("idade");

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor != null){
        Log.i("Nome: ",cursor.getString(colunaNome));
        Log.i("Idade: ",cursor.getString(colunaIdade));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
 }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O cursor está a ser acedido antes de `cursor.moveToFirst()`. Além que a condição do while retorna sempre true.

Faça assim:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT nome,idade FROM pessoas",null);

if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do{
        Log.i("Nome: ", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome")));
        Log.i("Idade: ", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("idade")));
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Fiz do jeito que você disse mas o erro ainda persiste... não entendo porque mesmo verificando com uma condição ele ainda acusa que o cursor não está inicializado da forma correta

Comment: Você tem aquele código todo num mesmo método?

Comment: Sim, tudo sendo executado na MainAcivity

Comment: Então o problema deve ser esse. Procure por SQLiteOpenHelper para saber como implementar o banco.

Comment: Eu criei outro projeto e copiei e colei o código e deu certo... Acho que o android studio bugou, mas muito obrigado